# scroll into the list that matches pressed key in the drop down

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, combobox

I am developing A UWP app and I have a dropdown with the list of country names, flag and country Codes. When I click on the drop down the list of countries opens. But, if I click and press any letter(e.g I) it does not scroll to the list automatically where the list starts with I.

I have tried adding IsTextSearchEnabled property to the drop down but I am not getting the desired result. Please can anyone guide me what needs to be done here?

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="CmbCountrylist" Height="auto" IsEditable="True" 
IsTextSearchEnabled="True" Width="250" Margin="0,0,1,0" Background="red" 
PlaceholderText="Select Country" 
SelectionChanged="CmbCountryCodes1_SelectionChanged" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>


<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding name}" >

<Image x:Name="ImgFlag" Width="16"  Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />

<TextBlock x:Name="txtCountryName" Text="{Binding name}" />
<TextBlock x:Name="txtCode" Text="{Binding dial_code}" />
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>          
<ComboBox.ItemsPanel>         
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>                                
</ComboBox.ItemsPanel>  

</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, the data source which binding is a class. In this case, please override the class's `ToString()` method to return the country name.

```cs
public class Country
{
   // other properties

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return name;
   }
}
```

When you enter text in a `ComboBox`, the `ComboBox` will match the data in the data list, but the `ComboBox` will not actively look for a property of the class, but instead look up the value of the `ToString()` method.

Best regards.

Comment: If the answer has resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later